# mouse and touchpad works selectively on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad with dual-boot of Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1
The touchpad works perfectly on Windows.
On Ubuntu, there are some functions that work. 
- I can do right and left click.
- If I hold and drag on the touchpad,it moves.
But nothing else works. I cant move on touchpad normally. Edge scrolling also doesnt work.

I've tried a lot of available solutions. removing and installing xserver-xorg-core did not help.
Also clearly the device is being deteted in xinput. 
I also checked out a lot of forums where modprobe was recommended.
I did this - sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
This gives me movement on touchpad but no tap-on-click or scrolling.
Other options like proto=bare or exps do the same thing.
I don't think that's the solution for me.

In /proc/bus/input/devices I found this:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input201
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

After changing psmouse I got this:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input203
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

I really don't know what the problem is to begin fixing it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having this same problem on a Gigabyte P25 that has a touchpad with the same vendor, product id, and version as yours. I posted about [the problem][oldquestion] previously and to date also have not received any responses. So far the only suggestion I can make is to file a [bug report][bgreport]. I have made all of my logs available on a [github repository][git]. [oldquestion]:http://askubuntu.com/questions/664443/synpatics-touchpad-occasionally-not-detected
[bgreport]:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection
[git]:https://github.com/j-devil/bugs/tree/master/touchpad